# Is there a proper discussion site for Windows 10 OS problems?

Tags: support, tags, site-recommendation

I have an issue with my Windows 10 OS that has me stumped and am not quite sure how to fix it.

Looking at Stack Overflow, it doesn't seem like the right place to post, neither does [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Is there a proper tag here that I didn't notice or maybe a Stack Exchange site for troubleshooting Windows 10?

Here is a description of the issues I am having. I am posting them here so that the exact questions I have can be directed to the proper tag or Stack Exchange site I am not expecting solutions:

1. Reconnect your drive, Your file history drive was disconnected for too long. Reconnect it and then tap or click to keep saving copies of your files.
2. Windows Search doesn't work. When I open it I can only type in 2 or 3 characters at most before it freezes and doesn't let me type anything else. It also doesn't display any results.
3. Files disappeared. I have 3 harddrives one for games (D) one for system stuff (C) and one for programs, GitHub, schoolwork and backups (E). For some reason my E drive doesn't have any data, my books, programs, and backups are not there, but the drive still has space allocated for everything.

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Try posting on superuser.com

Comment: Thank you after reading the tour it seems like the right place. If there are conflicts I will seek further help on the meta there.

Comment: You have a hard drive that's going bad. Back up everything you can, replace the drive and reinstall windows if it was your OS drive.  Nothing you can do to "fix" it.

Comment: @Will I don't have means to buy a new drive right now. So I'm copying its content onto an external backup I have. This drive is solely for extra data (books, class work, personal projects etc) so when I get a new drive would I just need to copy it over?

Comment: Uh, dunno.  You need to clarify greatly before you ask that on [su]

Comment: "Is there a proper discussion site for windows 10 OS problems?" -> Why yes! https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10?auth=1 . Just putting it out there, its still okay to go to the Vendor's site to look for help. The Q&A format is not fit for support needs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly you should note that that no sites are discussion sites. It's Q&A on all sites.

Superuser has a [windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-10)[tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10). Check the tag out and the questions that have been asked under it to see if yours would fit.

Those are 3 separate questions so make sure you ask separately with as much information as you can and don't forget to search on the site first in case your questions have already been asked.

To be honest there doesn't seem to be enough information in your questions to allow anyone on superuser to be able to answer them currently. You may want to seek help on [superuser's meta](https://meta.superuser.com/) to try to get your questions into shape first.